# Pass variable to custom Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I have an accordion list, in which I want to be able to open certain items.
I have created accordion-open directive, which should open the particular item if shouldBeOpen is true

**Here is the HTML element (items are printed in loop)**

```
<div class="m-list-item-head accordion-item" accordion-open="{{shouldBeOpen}}">
```

**And here is my custom directive**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp').directive('accordionOpen', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element) {
          if (open) {
            $(element).closest('.accordion-item').siblings().slideDown('fast');
            $(element).closest('.accordion-item').addClass('opened');
          }
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

I am not able to read the contents of accordion-open within the directive.

Answer (score 1):

The interpolate expressions are not required. So change to :

```
accordion-open="shouldBeOpen"
```

Next, add `attrs` to your link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs)
```

And use `$eval` to get the value of the attribute in your link function:

```
console.log(scope.$eval(attrs.accordionOpen))
```